# How to recognize certain words from a sentence with machine learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

So this is the problem: I have a list of names for various merchandise. The list(python 2.7) generally looks like: 
'''
['10 Apple phones','20W LED light bulb','Insignia™ - 450 Sq. Ft. Portable Air Conditioner','Jack Black Double-Duty Face Moisturizer SPF 20','apple']
'''
All the items are strings. Items in the list are completely random and have no obvious connection to each other.

Now what I want to extract from each string is the item itself, without the descriptions. For example, "10 Apple phones" becomes "phones"; "Insignia™ - 450 Sq. Ft. Portable Air Conditioner" becomes "Air Conditioner" and "apple" from the list is just "apple" (because that's exactly what it is).

The list after proper extraction looks like this (ideally): 
'''
['phones','light bulb','Air Conditioner','Face Moisturizer','apple']
'''

My frist approach was to find all the items that are similar and put them in one group (there are about 500k words in the dataframe). I then extracted the similar parts of the words in one group. For example, "iphone XS Max", "3 iPhone 4", "two iPhone 7s" and "iPhone 3g" would be put in one group, and the algorithm would extract the similar part, which is "iPhone" in this case.

This algorithm kind of worked in about 60% of the cases (I think it might get better if I optimize the algorithm a little bit more). But I'm looking for a different approach that will increase the accuracy. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: if you ask me, i really dont think machine learning is well suited for this task.

Comment: Did u try semantic similarity using wordnet ontology ?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the task of Named Entity Recognition

you should checkout the `spaCy` library

https://spacy.io/

specfically you can use the `PhraseMatcher` or `Matcher` component of `spaCy` which is intended for such purposes.

https://spacy.io/api/matcher

https://spacy.io/api/phrasematcher

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out!